# Prove that $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+1}{1-x}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}+\tan^{-1}(x)$

Tags: trigonometry

The question is:

> Prove that $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+1}{1-x}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}+\tan^{-1}(x)$.

It's from A-level further mathematics.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are a new user, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say what your thoughts on the problem are so far; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them write their answers at an appropriate level. Also, people are also much happier to help those who demonstrate that they've tried the problem themselves first.

Comment: Please see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/464/264) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/161783) for how to format your mathematics expressions with LaTeX, and see [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to use Markdown formatting. If you need to format more advanced math, there are many excellent LaTeX references on the internet, including Stack Exchange's own [TeX.SE site](http://tex.stackexchange.com/). If you see a piece of LaTeX you want to know the code for on the site, you can right click on it, go to "Show Math As", then choose "TeX Commands".

Comment: Given Problem is incorrect.
There should be (1-x) in place of (x-1).
You can check it simply by putting x=0(relation doesn't hold).

Comment: @E.O.: Marvis got the valid relation.problem is with the "problem".

Comment: Initially, I had the wrong sign as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The identity should read $$\tan^{-1} \left(\dfrac{x+1}{1-x} \right) = \tan^{-1}(x) + \pi/4$$

Let $\tan^{-1}(x) = \theta$ i.e. $x = \tan(\theta)$. Then we get that $$\dfrac{x+1}{1-x} = \dfrac{\tan(\theta) + 1}{1-\tan(\theta)}$$
Recall that $\tan(A+B) = \dfrac{\tan(A) + \tan(B)}{1 - \tan(A) \tan(B)}$.

Taking $B = \pi/4$, we get that $\tan(A+ \pi/4) = \dfrac{\tan(A) + 1}{1 - \tan(A)}$.

Hence, we get that
$$\dfrac{x+1}{1-x} = \dfrac{\tan(\theta) + 1}{1-\tan(\theta)} = \tan(\theta + \pi/4)$$
Hence, $$\tan^{-1} \left(\dfrac{x+1}{1-x} \right) = \theta + \pi/4 = \tan^{-1}(x) + \pi/4$$

**Proof of $\tan(A+B) = \dfrac{\tan(A) + \tan(B)}{1 - \tan(A) \tan(B)}$**

$$\tan(A+B) = \dfrac{\sin(A+B)}{\cos(A+B)} = \dfrac{\sin(A) \cos(B) + \cos(A) \sin(B)}{\cos(A) \cos(B) - \sin(A) \sin(B)}$$
Assuming $\cos(A) \cos(B) \neq 0$, divide numerator and denominator by $\cos(A) \cos(B)$, to get that
$$\tan(A+B) = \dfrac{\sin(A) \cos(B) + \cos(A) \sin(B)}{\cos(A) \cos(B) - \sin(A) \sin(B)} = \dfrac{\tan(A) + \tan(B)}{1 - \tan(A) \tan(B)}$$

Comment: @E.O. Yes edited accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: The identity holds only for $x\lt1$. Why is it so?

Answer (score 4):

Apply the function tan to both sides. Using the addition law for tan, we find that
$$\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\tan^{-1}x\right)=\frac{1+x}{1-x}.$$

But that is not what this answer is about.

Note that in the usual definition of $\tan^{-1} x$, we say that $\tan^{-1} x$ is the number (angle) in a **specific** interval whose tangent is $x$. For example, the Wikipedia definition specifies that $\tan^{-1} x$ is the number between $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ whose tangent is $x$.

Under that definition, the supposed identity is **not** correct. Take for example $x=\sqrt{3}$. Then $\tan^{-1} x= \frac{\pi}{3}$. So the right-hand side is greater than $\frac{\pi}{2}$, while the left-hand side is negative.

Similar considerations hold if we for example specify that $\tan^{-1}x$ lies between $0$ and $\pi$. We can make the identity correct by restricting $x$ to the interval $[0,1)$.

Comment: Would it also not hold for $x\lt0$?

Answer (score 3):

Although Marvis's answer is more complete (+1) that you had expected, I am adding other. We know that **If $f'(x) = g'(x)$, then $f(x) = g(x) + C$ for some constant $C$.**. Here, if you put $f(x)=\tan^{-1}(\frac{x+1}{1-x})$ and $g(x)=\tan^{-1}(x)$; then $f'(x) = g'(x)$. So there is a constant $C$ that $f(x) = g(x) + C$. Now, put $x=0$ into both sides of the latter equality.

[image: $f'(x) = g'(x)$]  [image: $f(x) = g(x) + \frac{\pi}{4}$]

Comment: What are the graphs?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: The first one shows that $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$ have the same graphs and the second one shows that graphs of  $\tan^{-1}(\frac{x+1}{1-x})$ and $\frac{\pi}{4}+\tan^{-1}(x)$ when $x<1$,coincides.

Comment: pretty graphics, again! + 1

Comment: Hi, without using graphs, can we prove that the result holds only for $x\lt1$?

Answer (score 0):

I'll resort to 2 very powerful formulas i did at school,often used, namely $\cos(2\tan^{-1}(x))=\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}$ and $\sin(2\tan^{-1}(x))=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$. After multiplying the both sides of the identity by 2
and taking cos
 of them, we simply get that:
$$\cos\left(2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+1}{1-x}\right)\right)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+2\tan^{-1}(x)\right) \tag1$$

The calculations to do here are very simple and immediately get that:

$$\frac{-2x}{x^2+1}=\frac{-2x}{x^2+1}.$$
Q.E.D.

Comment: But the result holds only for $x\lt1$, why is it so?